# How noisy is a saturated PNP BJT as a switch compared to a p-channel enhancement mode MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, switches, bjt, noise

I want to switch on phantom power (12V through 680ohm) electronically in order to guarantee simultaneous delivery and not have the comparatively low resistors load the input in case phantom power is not needed.  So they are to be switched on only on-demand.  The switch also powers a blue LED with about 1mA of current.

Now there are essentially two options:

a) run the LED driving current (split into two) through a pair of BJT transistors that have their emitters tied to 12V and use the collectors to drive phantom power through the resistors.

b) tie the LED anode (with the current determining resistor tied to 12V) to the gate of p-channel enhancement mode MOSFETs with their sources tied to 12V and their drains to the phantom power resistors.  Then grounding the LED cathode will switch on the MOSFETs.

Solution a) has the advantage that switching off phantom power will work even if 48V phantom power is supplied externally, while solution b) will get messy because the MOSFET body diodes will then engage in spite of the phantom power circuit supposed to be switched off.

The BJT transistors I am looking at are small-signal, high hFE, low-noise.  Still, I am dubious what saturation implies regarding noisiness.  There can be no smoothing circuit at the output side of the switching elements that wouldn't also affect the signal.  So the switched current needs to be clean when viewed at microphone input levels.

The LED current as such will likely be pretty noisy.  For the MOSFET solution that should be pretty irrelevant.  I feel queasy about the impact on the BJT solution.

Comment: A schematic proposal is required.

Comment: "Solution a) has the advantage that switching off phantom power will work even if 48V phantom power is supplied externally" -- you might want to check what the Veb limits are for typical BJTs.

Comment: @TimWilliams The base will be floating.  But you are right that Veb will still come into play because the BC diode would be forward-biased in that use case, and typical BE diodes act as 6.3V avalanche diodes in reverse bias (or is this just with NPN?).  So with a stipulated possible 48V of external voltage, my purported BJT advantage may be moot.

Comment: I just read 8 paragraphs and am little closer to understanding what the goal is.  Switching phantom power while not introducing noise?  Meanwhile, a schematic would say a thousand words.